# Can the tags "hyperlink" and "links" be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Similar tags:

- [hyperlink](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperlink) ×21 -- No description
- [links](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/links) ×275 -- A reference to another webpage that the user can follow (click on) to access that document.